# Tabulator number not shown > [object promise] shown

Tags: object, promise, numbers, tabulator

takeaway() is called in Tabulator, but is not shown in Tabulator. Tabulator throws a "[object promise]" message instead of showing the number of the variable number. How can this code be changed to show the number in Tabulator instead of the "[object promise]"? Tabulator of Olifolkerd. Tabulator probably only accepts sync (not async).

```js
function Restaurant() {
    return fetchOrders("/orders/" + orderID()").then(result => {
        menuNumber = result.data["menuNumber"];
        console.log("menuNumber = ", menuNumber);
    });
}

async function takeaway() {
    let number = await Restaurant();
    console.log("number = ", number);
    return number;
}
```

Comment: *"takeaway() is called in Tabulator*" - please post that part of the code

Comment: You change the tabulator code to use the same way for calling `takeaway` that you use in `takeaway` to call `Restaurant()` without getting a promise for the `number`.

Comment: As mentioned above, we can’t tell how you are using the async function with Tabulator. So, we can’t give you an answer. If you want a good answer, then you should create a working example that can be tested.

Comment: Never mind. I could add the data menuNumber in python in a different return body. So I removed the fetchOrders and all of the code which I shared above. Thank you for the help!